# Converting circular structure to JSON at Object.stringify (native) Knex Postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, ubuntu, knex.js

I have a basic table that one my postgresql db. I can insert data but I cannot update them.

```
projects
--id
--name

var db = require('knex')(config.posgresql);

db("projects").update({ name : 'bbb'}).then(function(value){
              console.log(value);
});
```

When I run the code it throws and error that says

> Unhandled rejection TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
>       at Object.stringify (native)
>       at QueryBuilder.Object.cloneIt (/home/barisv/king-server/helpers/extensions.js:406:28)
>       at Formatter.compileCallback (/home/barisv/king-server/node_modules/knex/lib/formatter.js:123:14)
>       at Formatter.parameter (/home/barisv/king-server/node_modules/knex/lib/formatter.js:45:36)

But when I run the code below it works.

```
db("projects").insert({ name : 'bbb'}).then(function(value){
                console.log(value);
              });
```

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

your code is missing a `where` condition. knex update follows this syntax

```
knex('books')
  .where('published_date', '<', 2000)
  .update({
    status: 'archived',
    thisKeyIsSkipped: undefined
  })
```

Comment: Where the doc says that ?

Comment: you need a condition or constraint to pick the row to update right? the code is found in the knexjs.org website.

Comment: If I dont put any where condition , it should update all the rows in that table, right ? Just like classic sql. Also I couldnt find any information that says you need a condition or constraint.

Comment: Does `knex` really support `thisKeyIsSkipped`? I thought it was `thisKeyIsSkippedForAllICare` :) LOL.